# Can you use 'correlation' in the following form?

Tags: grammar

Is this a correct usage of 'correlation"?

Studies indicates a correlation **between** A **with** B?

Ex:
Studies indicates a correlation **between** early exposure to music and song **with** future success in math and language.

Comment: I think this level of question is General Reference on ELU, but might be okay on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer

> correlation between A **and** B

or

> correlation of A **with** B

Answer (score 1):

The form most widely used is *a correlation between A **and** B*:

> - ...if there is a correlation between educational attainment *and* income level.
> - The Statistical Correlation between Crime *and* Poverty
> - Inverse correlation between plasma vitamin E *and* mortality from ischemic heart disease

Etc.

There is a slight problem using music *and* song *and*... which I would reword to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I would rephrase, using "between...and...," as follows:

> "Studies *indicate* a correlation between early exposure to music and *to songs* and future success in math and *languages*."

Comment: The repetition of 'to' in *to songs* sounds awkward (though I agree that your wording clarifies the relationships). One way around this awkwardness is to invoke the device of "on the one hand X, on the other hand Y": "Studies indicate a correlation between early exposure to music and song on the one hand, and future success in math and languages on the other."

Comment: @ErikKowal Yes! Sounds a lot better your way. :-)